# how to take inputs from two different files xml and json and display o/p

Tags: c#, .net

I have two input files xml and json and I want to display the o/p of the horses

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<meeting xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <date>16/12/2017</date>
  <MeetingType>HorseRacing</MeetingType>
  <track name="field" TranslatedName="field" club="R.C." location="M" country="US" state="IC" condition="Good3"/>
  <Meetingid>217</Meetingid>
  <races>
    <race number="1" name="Plate" id="114" Status="OPEN">
      <NumberOfRunners>13</NumberOfRunners>
      <start_time>16/12/2017 11:30:00 AM</start_time>
      <distance metres="1100"/>
      <horses>
        <horse name="Advancing" country="US" age="2" sex="C" colour="b" foaling_date="01/08/2015" id="99">
          <number>1</number>
          <trainer name="Price" id="495">
            <statistics>
              <statistic type="one_year" total="738" firsts="113" seconds="93" thirds="92"/>
            </statistics>
          </trainer>
          <training_location>field</training_location>
          <owners>New (Mgr:Murphy),  Racing Pty Ltd (Mgr: Teo), Horse Ventures (Mgr:blom) &amp;amp;  Farm Llc (Mgr: J Mul)</owners>
          <colours>Red, Yellow Stars And Halved Sleeves, Red Cap With White Newgate Logo</colours>
          <current_blinker_ind>N</current_blinker_ind>
          <prizemoney_won>0</prizemoney_won>
          <jockey name="M J Dee" id="15233">
            <statistics>
              <statistic type="one_year" total="717" firsts="71" seconds="64" thirds="80"/>
            </statistics>
          </jockey>
          <barrier>7</barrier>
          <weight allocated="57" total="57"/>
        </horse>
        <horse name="Corl" country="US" age="2" sex="C" colour="b" foaling_date="22/08/2015" id="42">
          <number>2</number>
          <trainer name="Ryan" id="371">
            <statistics>
              <statistic type="one_year" total="66" firsts="7" seconds="10" thirds="11"/>
            </statistics>
          </trainer>
          <training_location>field</training_location>
          <owners> Park (Mgr:  Douglas) &amp;amp; T Dav</owners>
          <colours>Royal Blue, Light Blue Hoops, White Cap</colours>
          <current_blinker_ind>Y</current_blinker_ind>
          <prizemoney_won>3000</prizemoney_won>
          <last_four_starts>05</last_four_starts>
          <last_ten_starts>05</last_ten_starts>
          <jockey name="Maloney" id="86">
            <statistics>
              <statistic type="one_year" total="488" firsts="70" seconds="61" thirds="74"/>
            </statistics>
          </jockey>
          <barrier>6</barrier>
          <weight allocated="57" total="57"/>
        </horse>
      </horses>
      <prices>
        <price>
          <priceType>WinFixedOdds</priceType>
          <horses>
            <horse number="1" Price="4.2"/>
            <horse number="2" Price="12"/>
          </horses>
        </price>
      </prices>
    </race>
  </races>
</meeting>
```

JSON:

```
{
  "FixtureId": "bphVf_Ik6LkkxYT5aN1MgQvcta0",
  "Timestamp": "2017-12-13T06:05:23Z",
  "RawData": {
    "FixtureName": "13:45 @hampton",
    "Id": "bphVf_Ik6LkkxYT5aN1MgQvcta0",
    "StartTime": "2017-12-13T13:45:00Z",
    "Sequence": 1,
    "Tags": {
      "CourseType": "Flat",
      "Distance": "0m 5f 21y",
      "Going": "Fast",
      "Runners": "9",
      "MeetingCode": "94209",
      "TrackCode": "hampton",
      "Sport": "HorseRacing"
    },
    "Markets": [
      {
        "Id": "NbSeMfzhDCHT_HdtAYZF_7zjFkI",
        "Selections": [
          {
            "Id": "b0Ut0-KyBdfknmjckAQHY1sxs3U",
            "Price": 10.0,
            "Tags": {
              "participant": "1",
              "name": "Toolatetodelegate"
            }
          },
          {
            "Id": "2GQLldt5t2lZCW93EgdBMwDIbP0",
            "Price": 4.4,
            "Tags": {
              "participant": "2",
              "name": "khaar"
            }
          }
        ],
        "Tags": {
          "Places": "3",
          "type": "winner"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Participants": [
      {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Toolatetodelegate",
        "Tags": {
          "Weight": "9st 7lbs",
          "Drawn": "8",
          "Jockey": "Carver",
          "Number": "1",
          "Trainer": "Barr"
        }
      },
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "khaar",
        "Tags": {
          "Weight": "9st 6lbs",
          "Drawn": "3",
          "Jockey": "Eaves",
          "Number": "2",
          "Trainer": "Ryan"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What ever may be the input form be it xml or json I want the horsenames with price in ascending order in a c# console application.

Can any one guide how to do this?

With price in ascending order, what ever may be input file we should display horse names with price in ascending order.

---

I am using code like this

```
 public static void convertJson()
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> horseDic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            string jsonData = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\..\FeedData\Race.json");
            dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonData);


            foreach (var item in jsonObj)
            {
                var itemName = item.Name;
                var itemValue = item.Value;
                if(itemName== "RawData")
                {
                  var itemMar=   item.Value.Find("Markets");

                }

            }


        }
```

but I don't know this is the right way.

Answer (score 2):

1) Create model classes for each of your sources. For xml you can try this: https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net for json this one: http://json2csharp.com

2) Deserialize your sources into objects.

3) Use linq to objects to derive the information you need